# Не работает nextLine()

Tags: java, ввод

При выборе 8 кейса не сохраняет результат в переменную. И как-то странно считывает (пропускает одну строку, и только тогда текст с клавиатуры)
Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
    menu : 

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch(menu) {
            case 0 : break menu;

            // case 1 - case 7

            case 8 :
                System.out.println("Введите слова для поиска : ");
                String search2 = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(search2);
                break;
            default : System.out.println("Ошибка");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте `scan.nextLine();` на `scan.next();` и все заработает как нужно. Пропуск строки - это не странность считывания, а вывод пустого `System.out.println(search2);` потом `break;` и считывание следующего `int menu = scan.nextInt();`

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    menu :
    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int menu = scan.nextInt();
        switch(menu) {
            case 0 : break menu;

            // case 1 - case 7

            case 8 :
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Введите слова для поиска : ");
                String search2 = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println(search2);
                break;
            default : System.out.println("Ошибка");
        }
    }
```

Comment: вот только мне нужно не одно слово ввести, а несколько, и сначала идет сканер а потом уже вывод, это не пустой System.out.println(search2);

Comment: После `nextInt` остается конец строки. Просто считайте его `scan.nextLine()` и потом читайте нужную вам строку.

Comment: Тогда действительно стоит сделать так, как в комментарии выше (код подправлен), или используйте BufferedReader. Тут пример использования того и другого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311266/read-line-with-scanner "BufferedReader is working fine."